# Нейросеть не сходится

Tags: нейронные-сети

Имеется многослойный полносвязный перцептрон с одним скрытым слоем. Функция активации - сигмоидальная. Обучаю методом обратного распространения ошибки. Её предназначение - распознавать рукописные цифры от 0 до 9. Количество входных данных 225(изображения цифр 15х15), количество скрытых слоев 50. Тренировочная выборка состоит из 500 изображений - по 50 вариаций на каждую цифру.

После обучения на тренировочной выборке средняя ошибка составляет около 5% и достигается довольно быстро. Но! Если посмотреть на самую минимальную ошибку и на самую максимальную из всех тренировочных примеров, то их разница составляет где-то 50%. То есть при тренировке минимальная ошибка постоянно стремиться к 0, а максимальная колебается в пределах 40 - 60%.

Пытался настраивать значения количества скрытых нейронов, скорость обучения и момент, но это не принесло особо позитивных результатов.

Нейросеть сходиться если я обучаю её лишь на 10 изображений цифр(по 1 варианту на каждую), тогда достигается баланс минимальной и максимальной ошибки. Иначе очень сильная разница, что приводит к порой странным результатам распознавания. В целом она распознает цифры, которые я её показываю, но не всегда верно.

Получается, что на некоторых изображения оно тренируется с ошибкой 0.0001%, а на некоторых 50% и больше. Что за бред?

С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1):

1. `sigmoid` используется для задач **бинарной** классификации (два класса, например является ли число на картинке нулем - Да/Нет), а у вас на выходе 10 классов (десять цифр), поэтому надо использовать `softmax` в качестве функции активации.
2. насколько мне известно многослойный перцептрон - не самый лучший алгоритм для распознавания картинок/образов. Для таких задач обычно используют [сверточные нейронные сети](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C).

Comment: У меня 4 выхода, которые описывают цифру в виде двоичного числа

Comment: если у вас на выходе 4 числа (класса), то и предсказываете вы в итоге 4 числа. Иначе как вы их различать будете?

Comment: выход [0, 0, 0, 0] равняеться нулю, [0, 0, 0, 1] - один [0, 0, 1, 0] - два и так далее. Получается до 15, но при обучении я использую только цифры до 9, то есть до [1, 0, 0, 1]

Comment: @MaxU ТС имеет в виду следующую модель. Положим, выход такой: `0.48 - 0.3 - 0.58 - 0.62` -> `0 - 0 - 1 - 1` -> `3` // Пока я писал, это уже описал сам ТС хД

Comment: @RealPeha, это потому что вы неправильно построили модель. Если сделать правильно то на выходе будет вектор вероятностей из десяти элементов - индекс элемента с максимальной вероятностью будет представлять цифру

Comment: @MaxU, а если уже невозможно переделать нейросеть под софтмакс функцию активации? Иначе эта проблема никак не решается?

Comment: грубо говоря, `sigmoid` - хорош для того чтобы предсказывать ответ Да/Нет. Поэтому для задач мультиклассовой классификации используют [`softmax`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax). Подумайте подходит ли вам ответ Да/Нет для предсказания 10 различных цифр? ;-)